# How to draw Flag on Face Or Paint Or Overlay Image on Face or another Image in Android pragmatically

Tags: android

I am developing a project in Android to Draw/Overlay/Paint flag or other image on Face. Or Draw/Overlay/Paint an Image with another image i.e. embed image into other. But the second image should be exact on the face. Take a close look below

[image: See this picture]

I am using the Face Detection Vision Api of Google, and get the Landmarks and even whole face and draw a simple rectangle around using An Introduction to Face Detection on Android

But the Question is:

- How to draw image on another image as shown above?
- Am I on the right path i.e. Face Detection and then draw something?

Please give me some sample code that how to start with or give me some github libs if available. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could've been a comment, but i felt like sharing this idea as an answer.

***Note*** that this is just an idea

I have used Google's Vision API but that was quite some time ago. As far as i remember, you can draw a rectangle over a face and get it's positions aka landmarks. You can make use of that.

Instead of writing a complicated `paint` function where you have to draw a `Bitmap`, rather construct a new `ImageView`. Set it's height and width by calculating the position/landmark of the rectangle and also position the new `ImageView` over the rectangle. Positioning the `ImageView` might be relatively easier as you have the rectangles XY coordinates(i guess). Then simply set it's source as the flag image or anything you want. You can set the opacity(`alpha` value) of the `ImageView` to a lower value to make it blend it.

If you want to only paint the **face** and not create an overlay, that's a different topic. You will need to take a few pixels from the face, get their color values, then `paint` the other image over that. It's not gonna be easy, but i guess this is the way to go.

Guidelines :

[Getting color of pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391353/get-color-of-each-pixel-of-an-image-using-bufferedimages)

[Drawing images pixel by pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297504/draw-image-pixel-by-pixel-in-java)

Comment: I only want to paint face .. if i use your idea then image will be overlayed in rectangle